# Sentence construction using would

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

I want to ask my boss that if our company bus goes near from his home then will he travel 45 min to railway station.

> Would you travel 45 min to railway station if bus goes near from your home.
>
> Would you travel 45 Min to railway station if bus would passing near from your home.
>
> Would you travel 45 min to railway station if bus has passed near from your home.
>
> Would your travel 45 min to railway station if bus is passing near from your home.

Which of these is best? Please correct me if none of the above are correct.

Comment: None of the above are acceptable English sentences, but I don't understand the context. How does the boss currently get to work? What options will be available to him in future?

Comment: currently he is regularly travling by train. He dont wish to come by company bus because it takes 45 min to him to reach designated company bus stop. so if i send company bus will he come by bus. so i want to ask him would he come by bus if bus would pass near from his home. i mean his home is on the way of bus route.

Comment: I'm still confused. Surely what matters is *how long it takes your boss to get to work*, not how long it takes him to get to a bus stop or train station. I'm not even sure if you're asking him this question because you really want to know if he is willing to change his travel arrangements. Or is it perhaps rhetorical, as in *"Would you vote for Christmas if you were a turkey?"* (where the obvious and expected answer is *"Definitely not!"*).

Comment: @sanket: Now I am confused. Does he take 45 minutes to travel to Bus Station or Railway Station?

Comment: Would he stop travaling 45 min to railwaystation, if bus would come to the stop which is near to his house. There are 2 conditions 1) boss willingness to come to bus stop. 2) If bus come to stop near his home.

Answer (score 2):

Having encountered some grammatical errors in the comments, I'll submit this solution.

> "Would you still travel for 45 minutes to get to the railway station if the bus passed by/near your house?"

The exact wording can be changed slightly, but I'm adamant we need a second conditional (If + past, conditional) since we're mulling a hypothetical situation.

Comment: My answer? "That depends - is the bus going to stop at my house? Or just pass by?" (That's only a joke; the answer here does a good job of asking the question, which is why I've upvoted this answer.)

Comment: :) - nice response. Always enjoy a nice bit of semantic humour!

Answer (score 1):

For context I will assume that currently your boss travels 45 minutes to the railway station because the bus does not go near his home and you want to ask your boss that if the bus passes by his home would he still go to the railway station.

I believe that you are confused about how to state "bus goes near from his home".

You can use "passes by your house".

The correct sentence would be then:

> If the bus passes by your house, would you still be travelling 45 minutes to the railway station?

OR

> Would you still be travelling 45 minutes to the railway station, If the bus passes by your house.

Comment: Thanks dipak in hindi if i say. "Kya aap 45 min traval karte agar bus aapke ghar ke pas se jati". how to translate in english.

Comment: @sanket: A tip for you for better verbal English. Many people think in their native language and then translate the sentence bit by bit to English. This will not work. 

Both Languages may have entirely different grammatical structure. So think what you want to say and build the sentence using English grammar rules only.

Comment: Would he stop travaling 45 min to railwaystation, if bus would come to the stop which is near to his house. There are 2 conditions 1) boss willingness to come to bus stop. 2) If bus come to stop near his home. –

Comment: @sanket I already told you once that if you have clear idea in Hindi, do message me (I can create a chat, a private chat for Indians for that sake). It'll be easy for you to get answer at once.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12530/hindi-speakers-room for Hindi speakers like us.

Comment: @sanket: In that case you may use the sentences I have used in the answer

Comment: @sanket *Kya aap 45 min traval karte agar bus aapke ghar ke pas se jati.* - the translation in English would be: *Would you travel 45 minutes if (given the option of) the bus would pass nearby your house?*

Comment: Thanks Deepak, Moauik, fumble fingar for clarification. it is clear now. Thanks a ton

Comment: Thanks Maulik V surely we have chat. Please create a chat for me

Comment: I don't agree (native British speaker) with the use of the second "would". The sentence (imo) should be: "Would you still travel for 45 minutes to get to the railway station if the bus **passed** by/near your house?"