# two conditions in one sentence using would

Tags: conditional-constructions

Please help me with following sentence construciton.
I want to use two conditions using if and would.

Senario is our office bus is not passing near from my bosss residence hence he prefer to travel by train every day. I want to ask him if Office Bus route would have near from his residence or bus passes near from his residence, then would he travel by bus instade of train every day.

So if i say

Would you travel by train if our office bus passes near from your home.
or
Would you travel by train if our office bus would pass near from your home.
or
would you travel by train if our office bus is passing near from your home.

Comment: Why do I have a deja-vu? This question really seems familiar - about trying to convince your boss to travel by bus.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/sentence-construction-using-would

Comment: No my Query is not same. Hear i want say can i use would if both conditions are happening every day.

Comment: For that every day activity, use the simple present in the second part, as in the accepted answer in the linked question. I do find it funny that several people have to convince their someone top travel by bus. Do so many people prefer taking a 45 minutes train trip to taking a bus, and do they often have to be convinced to take the bus?

Comment: Actually the scenario is I stop company bus near my resident for my convenience. This is because designated bus stop is 45 minutes away from my home. This is not as per company policy to stop bus any ware.
Hence my boss asked me to travel 45 instead of stopping bus near my house.
My boss is also traveling by train to avoid 45 minute travel to catch bus.
For this I want to tell him that.
Would he ready to travel 45 minutes every day to catch bus, if the bus would go near from his home every day?

Comment: Is "ply" a typo here? I don't understand your second clause. I think the most natural way to say this in English is, "Would you still travel 45 minutes to the railway station every day even if our office bus stopped by your home?" But "would you travel to the railway station every day if our office bus would stop by your home" doesn't sound totally foreign either. the "ply" I don't understand.

Comment: @hunter I had too look it up, but [ply](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ply) can be used in the sense of "to go or travel regularly". I would advise against using that verb here though :)

Comment: @user4084: I still see many similarities between this question and the other one that was linked. The train vs. the bus, the 45 minute travel and almost the exact same sentence. Anyway, I still do not see how your question is not answered by the accepted answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any grammatical rule that would prohibit someone from using the word *would* twice in a single question. However, when I tried to think of a few examples, I kept noticing that the question would improve significantly if there was only one *would*.

> If I would drop your favorite vase, would you still love me?
> **Better:** If I dropped your favorite vase, would you still love me?
>
> Would you file for divorce, if I would put poison in your soup?
> **Better:** Would you file for divorce, if I put poison in your soup?
>
> Would you stop nagging me, if I would change the oil?
> **Better:**  Would you stop nagging me, if I changed the oil?

However, in some situations, you can get away with *would* twice, if you include a word like *just* or *even*:

> Would you stop nagging me, if I would just change the oil?

Back to your question; I'd phrase it like this:

> Would you ***still*** travel 45 minutes to the railway station everyday, ***even*** if our office bus stopped near your home?

There is no need to for the second *would* (it doesn't accomplish anything, except to make the sentence more awkward). The word *still* informs the reader in that the person currently takes the train; I think it's a critical word in this context. The word *even* is not quite as vital, but I still think it helps express the hypothetical nature of the question.

Comment: I would add that the sentence could be made clearer by employing the subjunctive mood: *Would you travel 45 minutes to the railway station everyday, if our office bus were to stop near your home?*